# Can I deploy worker roles to windows azure pack?

Tags: windows, azure, pack

I am planning to install windows azure pack on windows server 2012 r2. I primarily want to run worker roles on it.

Is this possible? Documentation does not clearly say whether this is supported or not

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "no". PaaS Cloud Services are not part of the Azure Pack currently.

That said, a properly architecture solution can be deployed both on-premises and in the cloud. Its just the way they are deployed and managed needs to be different. In your specific case, it should be a fairly simple matter to take the worker role, isolate the business functionality into its own class library, and have that class called from both a worker role (cloud PaaS) as well as a Windows Service (on-premises)

Comment: Makes sense. I just don't want to deal with windows services right now as I like the cloud worker role deployment and update mechanism better. Why is it not supported when web sites are?

Answer (score 0):

As Brent mentioned, it is not supported on Azure Pack.

**You should give Azure Service Fabric a try, they do seamless integration between Azure and On-premise and from the looks of things you are building a single web application with pieces on on-premise and on the cloud.**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-fabric/

A good channel 9 introduction video

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Service-Fabric-101-Introduction

**To give a bit deeper answer on why is websites there and cloud services not there on Azure pack :** 
Azure Cloud Services is a very good PaaS offering that have been successful in Azure because of it high reliability, freedom and solid performance. **The fabric is the layer of abstraction that the cloud services run on that manages machines, restarts machines on update, maintains update domains, network switches, DNS etc.** Bringing fabric to on-premise is a difficult tasks as it requires a lot of work from the on-premise owner to set things up like an Azure data center on his company network. A lot of things can go wrong here. It is possible but don't know how it would have panned out.

**Websites however are easier to be modeled into on-premise as we have all the pieces on the machines and we have server farms in IIS that allows us to manage the machines easily required for hosting websites.**

Hope the Answer help, **Try Azure Service Fabric for your scenario, it is pretty cool :).**
**Happy to help, - CB**